# Is it make sense to wrap mongoose model to own API?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, node-mongodb-native

I'm trying to understand is it make sense to make own API for working with Mongoose models?

Let's say we have the simple Mongoose user model:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: 'string', required: true, unique: true, lowercase: true },
  password: { type: 'string', required: true },
  name: {type: 'string'}
});

var UserModel = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

For a abstract application, User model should have methods like 'create', 'delete', 'update', 'find', 'authenticate' and so on. So I have two approach to achieve this purpose:

1. Include these methods into a Mongoose Model like the following:

   ```
   UserSchema.static('create', function (data, callback) {
        var user = new User(data);
        user.save(function (err) {
            if (err) return callback(err);

            return callback(null, user);
       });
    });
   ```
2. Wrap a method in a custom User class like this:

   ```
   UserProvider = function(){};

   UserProvider.prototype.create = function(data, callback) {
        var user = new User(data);
        user.save(function (err) {
            if (err) return callback(err);

           return callback(null, user);
        });
    };
   ```

In the first one I can to create a new user like this:

```
UserModel.create({name: 'test'}, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {// do something}
});
```

And in the second one I can create a new similar:

```
var userProvider= new UserProvider();
userProvider.create({name: 'test'}, function (err, user) {
     if (err) {// do something} 
});
```

Although these approaches look similar I feel I need choose that don't break Mongoose API in a future.

Please tell me which is approach looks better for mongoose models?

Comment: Personally I like the first usage

Comment: Yes I too. But what happens if Mongeese will have a 'create' method in a future?

Comment: I think any way, you will need to keep your code up-to-date with every version of Mongeese.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose models have native `create`, `update`, and `find` methods, so method one would already break Mongoose if you tried to add those.

You could use method two (which feels messy to me), but it's probably cleaner to use the existing Mongoose methods as your provider API pattern and just add the ones you need that are not provided natively via static functions.  Either that or add your own full set of methods that have names that use a unique prefix (e.g. `my_create`, `my_update`, etc.).

But make sure it's clear to you why you're adding an abstraction layer, as the added indirection and complexity doesn't come free.

Comment: Maybe I need to swiych to node-mongodb-native? Do you have a expamples in making Provider API for node-mongodb-native?

Comment: @Erik What are you specifically looking to achieve with your Provider API abstraction?  An ability to mock the DB?  DB vendor independence?  Something else?

Comment: I need to have a inheritance, best performance and I want know what happening with my models.